# Upgrading from Storybook 6 to Storybook 7 results in a "process is not defined" error in my vue3 app

Tags: vuejs3, storybook

I upgraded front Storybook 6 to Storybook 7. These packages are all in my devDependencies but when I run my main vue3 app it won't show and the console shows this error:

```
[Vue Router warn]: Unexpected error when starting the router: ReferenceError: process is not defined
at node_modules/util/util.js (util.js:109:1)
at __require (chunk-AC2VUBZ6.js?v=2a7792e7:11:50)
at node_modules/assert/build/internal/assert/assertion_error.js (assertion_error.js:35:16)
at __require (chunk-AC2VUBZ6.js?v=2a7792e7:11:50)
at node_modules/assert/build/assert.js (assert.js:36:22)
at __require (chunk-AC2VUBZ6.js?v=2a7792e7:11:50)
at assert.js:631:31
```

It fails on the `app.use(router);` statement in my (stripped down) main.js listed below. Do you have any pointers for me to figure this one out?

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem in a Sveltekit project I was upgrading to Storybook 7.  It's a [Vite related issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1973#issuecomment-787571499).  I solved it by adding the following in .storybook/main.ts

```
async viteFinal(config) {
  (config.define = { 'process.env': {} });
  // as a bonus you can also add storybook specific aliases here:
  (config.resolve.alias = {
    $storybook: path.resolve('.storybook'),
  });
  return config;
}
```